# Javascript condition - show an element if checkbox condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm new in Javascript and Jquery, so I'm having a problem.

Here is a code which checks if three checkboxes are checked, and at last - condition- if all of those three are checked, show an html element.

```
$('input[class^="class"]').click(function() {    var $this = $(this); 
    if ($this.is(".class1")) {
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
            $(".class1").not($this).prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
            $(".class").prop("checked", true);
            setTimeout(function() { $('#2').click(); }, 1000); //oncheck moves to the next question
            var questionOne = 1;
        } else {
            $(".class1").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }

   if($this.is(".class2")) {
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
            $(".class2").not($this).prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
            $(".class").prop("checked", true);
            setTimeout(function() { $('#3').click(); }, 1000);
            var questionTwo = 1;
        } else {
            $(".class2").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }

   if($this.is(".class3")) {
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
            $(".class3").not($this).prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
            $(".class").prop("checked", true);
            setTimeout(function() { $('#4').click(); }, 1000);
            var questionThree = 1;
        } else {
            $(".class3").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }

 if(questionOne = 1 && questionTwo = 1 && questionThree = 1) { alert("alert on Page load"); }                                             
});
```

I guess the problem is either in setting variables or in the last condition.

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards,
Joni

Comment: `if(questionOne = 1...` - using `=` *assigns* the value 1 to the variable. To *test* the value use `===` or `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your last condition checks to:

```
if(questionOne === 1 && questionTwo === 1 && questionThree === 1) { 
    alert("alert on Page load"); 
}
```

You can get some basic knowledge about comparison in javascript at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 1):

Bro, do u mean like that?.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="get" class="check1">
<input type="checkbox" name="get2" class="check2">
<input type="checkbox" name="get3" class="check3">
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var  checkAndShow = function (){
        return ($('.check1').is(':checked')&&$('.check2').is(':checked')&&$('.check3').is(':checked'));
    }

    $('.check1,.check2,.check3').on('change', function(e){
        if(checkAndShow()){
            //show your div here
        }
        else{
            //hide your div here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed.